# Filter a nested json by a key value using jq

Tags: json, filter, jq, data-transform

Novice jq user here, trying to filter a nested json using jq.

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "item01",
        "description": "item01 description",
        "skus": [
          {
            "color": "blue",
            "precision": 2,
            "details": {
              "longDescription": "This a long description with a keywordA"
            }
          },
          {
            "color": "green",
            "precision": 1,
            "details": {
              "longDescription": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "item02",
        "description": "item02 description",
        "skus": [
          {
            "color": "red",
            "precision": 2,
            "details": {
              "longDescription": ""
            }
          },
          {
            "color": "yellow",
            "precision": 1,
            "details": {
              "longDescription": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "title": "item01",
  "color": "blue",
  "longDescription": "This a long description with a keywordA"
}
```

I am able to get the title and the description `jq '.data.products[] | {title: .title, longDescription: .skus[].details.longDescription } | select(.longDescription | contains("keywordA") )'`
Result:

```
{
  "title": "item01",
  "longDescription": "This a long description with a keywordA"
}
```

However, if I include color in the filter, I get inaccurate data.
`jq '.data.products[] | {title: .title, color:.skus[].color, longDescription: .skus[].details.longDescription } | select(.longDescription | contains("keywordA") )'`

```
{
  "title": "item01",
  "color": "blue",
  "longDescription": "This a long description with a keywordA"
}
{
  "title": "item01",
  "color": "green",
  "longDescription": "This a long description with a keywordA"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, but the following filter, which uses a "generate and test" approach, does produce the desired result and illustrates some possible techniques:

```
.data.products[]
| {title} + (.skus[] | {color} + (.details | {longDescription}))
| select(.longDescription | contains("keywordA"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, although I don't understand what you did in the middle of the query, i.e. `(.skus[] | {color} + (.details | {longDescription}))`, but I'll try to figure out.