# How do I use jq to read nested JSON array and return single value to variable?

Tags: json, bash, nested, jq

I have a simple JSON file used to store environment information.

```json
{
  "environments": {
    "dev": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "vm-IP": "ww.www.ww.ww",
        "sql-name": "vmname1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com",
        "status": "inactive"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "vm-IP": "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
        "sql-name": "vmname2.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com",
        "status": "active"
      }
    ],
    "stg": {
      "id": "3",
      "vm-IP": "yy.yyy.yy.yy",
      "sql-name": "vmname3.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
    },
    "prod": {
      "id": "4",
      "vm-IP": "zz.zzz.zz.zz",
      "sql-name": "vmname4.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Using a Bash environment, I am trying to read the IP addresses. Here is my successful script for "stg":

```
# This script works as expected b/c "stg" is not an array
# See STG objects
varFileName=myJsonFile.json
jq '.environments.stg' $varFileName

# Get the IP of stg
stgIP=$(jq -r '.environments.stg."vm-IP"' $varFileName)
echo $stgIP
```

I would like to get the environments.dev."vm-IP" that is active. Here are my unsuccessful scripts for "dev".

```
# These scripts do not work

# Get the IP of dev 2
devIP=$(jq -r '.environments.dev[]."vm-IP" | select(.status == "active")' $varFileName)
error: Cannot index string with string "status"

# this also does not work
devIP=$(jq -r '.environments.dev[]."vm-IP" | 
select(.environments.dev[].status == "active")' $varFileName)
error: Cannot index string with string "environments"
```

Please provide assistance with `jq` filtering.

**Related SO questions**

- [parsing nested json keys with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911183/parsing-nested-json-keys-with-jq)
- [Filter a nested json by a key value using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978470/filter-a-nested-json-by-a-key-value-using-jq)
- [Using jq to parse nested JSON arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081424/using-jq-to-parse-nested-json-arrays)
- [Use jq to interpret nested JSON in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101660/use-jq-to-interpret-nested-json-in-json)
- [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) (this ID is about setting variables and does not use `jq` at all)
- [Escape field name in jq that contains '@' and '-'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494389/escape-field-name-in-jq-that-contains-and) (this ID is about setting variables with a very simplistic JSON example.  The focus of this new question is about using `jq` to read nested JSON.)

Comment: See [how to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash), and [how to escape a field name in jq that contains a '-'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494389/escape-field-name-in-jq-that-contains-and), and try `stgIP="$(jq -r '.environments.stg."vm-IP"' "$varFileName")"` (Note that your attempts also feature `vm-ID` instead of `vm-IP`, and `$fileName` instead of `$varFileName`.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and additional links.  I have fixed my copy/paste errors, and appreciate your feedback.  Link 1 - "...variable to the otuput of a command..." doesn't use `jq`, so that isn't what I'm looking for.  Link 2 "...escape field name..." has such a simple JSON example, I'm not finding an answer there.

Comment: "How to set a variable to the output of a command" shows you how to run _any_ command and capture its output. In very brief, `variable=$(jq 'script' inputfile)`; with your latest edit, see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: If you peel off the `select(.status=="active")` from your first attempt, you will see that the result at that point is a sequence of strings, none of which have further attributes, or, in particular, a field named `"status"`. You need to run the `select()` on the values which _have_ this attribute: `jq -r '.environments.dev[] | select(.status=="active") | ."vm-IP"'`

Comment: @tripleee, thank you so much! Life Off!!